# How to expose explicitly the behavior of ReplaySubject or BehaviorSubject without exposing the Observer part?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

```
public class Foo
{
    private ReplaySubject<bool> whenBarChanged = new ReplaySubject<bool>();
    public IObservable<bool> WhenBarChanged
    {
        get { return whenBarChanged; }
    }
}
```

This code is exposing an interface that's IObservable, and the only way to expose the behavior of the subject is through documentation.

Do you know other way to expose the Observable part of Subject is working without exposing the  Observer part ?

Comment: The need to expose knowledge of the implementation is a design smell. All the clients should need to know is that WhenBarChanged is an IObservable<bool>

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AsObservable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211761%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to hide the identity of an observable.

```
public class Foo
{
    private ReplaySubject<bool> whenBarChanged = new ReplaySubject<bool>();
    public IObservable<bool> WhenBarChanged
    {
        get { return whenBarChanged.AsObservable(); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither `ReplaySubject` nor `BehaviorSubject` have any methods that are not part of either `IObserver<T>` or `IObservable<T>`.  What "behavior" are you wanting to expose that is not in either of those interfaces?

Comment: BehaviorSubject will always trigger the last value and ReplaySubject the whole sequence. I want give the information to whom will use this class that's the expected behavior of the IObservable. If I use IObservable this information is not transmitted via the type and if I use XXXSubject then I expose the Observer part too.

Comment: There is not a way to do that other than through documentation.  It is a limitation of the language that we cannot express the grammar of the observable.  In the system I am working on, we have many such `IObservables` that we have documented will always start with "the most recent known value" when you subscribe.